# Got trouble to casting value in simple query: "Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query

```
SELECT
    Id AS [ID]
    IIF(max(ISNULL(c.Value, 1.0)) = 1.0, 0.0, SUM(
                   CAST((IIF(ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(f.Value, 0.0)) = 1.0, CAST(f.Value AS float), 0.0) /
                         ISNULL(c.Value, 1.0)) *
                        60.0 AS float))) AS [Value]
FROM 
    Form f LEFT JOIN Control c ON f.ID = c.FormID
GROUP BY 
    f.Id
```

I get an error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with my code?

Here is my data of Form table and Control table:

```
tbl_Control:
Id   Value          FormID
1    12200.0000016  16382 
2    0              18864
3                   18234

tbl_Form:
ID       Value
16382    5 
18864    2019-12-24T02:01:05.660Z 
318234   Test OK
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi, I have updated the demo data above also the actual formula in my query, thanks for your request

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert a value to a number, then uses `try_convert()`.  For instance:

```
select id,
       max(try_convert(int, f.value)) as value
from form f
group by f.id;
```

Of course, this assumes that "number" means integer.  But you can use any type -- `numeric`, `real` and so on -- if those are more appropriate.

Also:  This will not return an error for overflows either.  When the conversion fails, the function returns `NULL`.